# Can't retrieve records using foreign key on the same table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 to retrieve records from a database.

My table (simplified):

```
services:
id
name
parent_id
```

parent_id is FK to the same table (FK to services.id).

This code returns an empty collection:

```
$category->services->where( 'parent_id', 0 )
```

Select with other where condition works properly. ex.

```
$category->services->where( 'name', 'foo )
```

returns not empty results.

Raw SQL works fine too:

```
SELECT * FROM services WHERE parent_id = 0;
```

What is wrong with Eloquent or how to use it in a way where I can retrieve records with concrete parent_id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
$services = $category->services()->where('parent_id', 0)->get()
```

Comment: Tried to do in this way, got
`Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Comment: Make sure you are using parenthesis `()` with `services` as `services()`.

Comment: Thanks! Wasted couple of hours for this - forgot basics.

Comment: couldn't earlier than in 7 mins )